# Framerate independent update using SDL?

Tags: sdl, render, frame-rate

This is my main loop:

```
while (!done)
{

    oldTimeMS = timeMS;
    timeMS = SDL_GetTicks();
    frameTimeMS = timeMS - oldTimeMS;
    frameTime = ((float)timeMS / 1000.0f)*FPS;

    update();
    render();
}
```

Where FPS is 60. I can framerate-independently update a variable by doing doing

```
var = var+increment*frameTime;
```

But how can I make it so that update() is only called after a certain interval (in time, not in frames) has passed? I want render() to be called as often as possible, every frame. But I want update() to only be called at a time-based interval. How can I set this up using these variables? Thank you in advance.

Edit:
Wait... Wouldn't I want update() to be called as much as possible until the next frame renders? How would I go about doing this? Would it be a better idea than my previous idea?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking is "tick based rendering loop"

http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Main_Loop_with_Fixed_Time_Steps.shtml

Comment: Check here for another example (you want the CFPS class): http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-opengl-tutorial-basics/